# Can Not add my self as admin in the facebook page

Tags: facebook, openid

Hey guys I think I screwed my self up here but hope you will be able to help me out.

I have recently added the facebook like button my home page, I did not create a page for it but linked it to my facebook app id before I made a page and used its actual page ID.

`<meta property="fb:page_id" content="APPID" />`

So when I clicked like it created a new page for my website however I can not add my self as the admin.
I have added fb:admins meta tag.

`<meta property="fb:admins" content="USERID" />`

I still cannot add my self as the admin, any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook caches everything so probabily it "saved" the link without you as the admin.

A possible solution for this is to refresh facebook's cache using the URL Linter found here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ .
Just enter the url where the the like button is installed and it will refresh the information.

Comment: Alrighty so I have used the facebook url linter and it flagged a few mising tags I added my self as an admin using the `<meta property="fb:admins" content="11111111" />` tag but I still cannot add my self as admin in manage admins section, could you please help me further??